# Java Process stops early even when output is redirected

Tags: java, process

I have a Java application that calls a tcsh script which in turn calls a perl script in the same directory. If I run this script from the command by typing "runPerlScript.sh", it works completely fine, and generates several output files as it should. However, if I call the script from Java, using the code below:

```
    String[] runCmd  = {"/bin/tcsh","-c","/filepath/runPerlScript.sh"};
    Process run = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(runCmd);

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(run.getInputStream()));

    String line = "";
    line = reader.readLine();
    System.out.println("\nStarting while.");
    while((line)!=null){
        System.out.println("Output from script: "+line);
        line=reader.readLine();
    }
    reader.close();
    System.out.println("Finished running perl script.");
```

it prints out the echo statements from my shell script to my console (I'm using NetBeans), but generates only 4 output files (when normally it generates near 50). It seems as if the process is quitting to early, because after these 4 files are generated, an echo statement in my shell script that says "Finished running runPerlScript.sh" prints out to my console. I've tried several different ways to run this script, including ProcessBuilder, but none seem to generate the output files. The code I have above was in fact the only way I was able to generate ANY output, because ProcessBuilder just resulted in hangups. Does anyone know how I can continuously make the script run?

Answer (score 1):

From the Runtime.exec() javadoc:

> "Executes the specified string command in a separate process."

Assuming you want to wait for the process to end, you will need to wait for the process to terminate in your main java thread. The best way to do this would be by monitoring the Process returned by ProcessBuilder.start() and wait with Process.waitFor().

Comment: Even with the Process.waitFor() method there is still no change in the output generated. It's still only 4 files and Java believes that it has run to completion.

Comment: Have you tried running the script directly rather than calling tcsh (assuming your shebang line states #!/bin/tcsh).

Comment: Yes, still only generates 4 files :(

Comment: What does process.exitValue() tell you?

Comment: ^Tried that too before I posted this question. It still only generates 4 files.

Comment: It produces an Exit Value of 0.

Comment: Sounds more like something dodgy is going on in your tcsh/perl script.

Comment: ^That's what I suspected to, but I was hoping this was not the case because I haven't learned Perl enough to debug it. I really appreciate  your help, though. Thanks.

Comment: If you can provide any of the tcsh/perl code we could have a further look.

Comment: The thing is it doesn't seem like anything is wrong with the Perl script because it runs perfectly well from the command line. It just seems like there is some problem within Java that I'm not seeing.

Comment: And besides the Perl script is extremely long and it would take a lot of time to parse out exactly which part is troublesome.

Comment: Tried calling the perl script directly rather than via the tcsh script?

Comment: Yes, I've tried calling the Perl script directly and it works, and I've also tried calling my shell script directly, and that works as well, which is why I'm extremely confused as to why it doesn't run in Java.

Comment: No but I mean have you tried calling the perl script directly from Java :-)

Comment: Yes I have, but that resulted in my Java program continually running with no files being generated or no output being generated, as if it hung up.

Comment: Then I'm in the dark. Let me know if you figure it out ;-)